# ActiveJob::SerializationError - Unsupported argument type: Time / DateTime

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I am using Rails 5 and ActiveJob to process background tasks.  I am trying to pass a object serialized with `as_json` to my job but I am receiving the following errors:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: Time):
ActiveJob::SerializationError (Unsupported argument type: DateTime):
```

I understand that ActiveJob will not take Time/DateTime objects due to some queueing systems not handling those type.  So the object I am trying to serialize is as follows:

```
card = Card.first
=> #<Card id: 256, title: "quis", description: "Sunt corporis error laudantium veritatis impedit r...", due_date: "2016-12-15 12:00:00", slug: "quis", created_at: "2016-11-30 17:00:01", updated_at: "2016-11-30 17:00:01", list_id: 26, position: 0, period_type: "hours", period_length: 0.0, user_id: 1>
```

When I run:

```
card.as_json
=> {"id"=>256, "title"=>"quis", "description"=>"Sunt corporis error laudantium veritatis impedit repellat quasi.", "due_date"=>Wed, 15 Dec 2016 12:00:00 UTC +00:00, "slug"=>"quis", "created_at"=>Wed, 30 Nov 2016 17:00:01 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 30 Nov 2016 17:00:01 UTC +00:00, "list_id"=>26, "position"=>0, "period_type"=>"hours", "period_length"=>0.0, "user_id"=>1}
```

The created_at, updated_at and due_date are all instances of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

I have tried to override this by using the following code in a initializer, which I found in another SO post but it does not help:

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = {})
        strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    end
end
```

Could anyone help with possibly have the dates as strings when `as_json` is run on the object?

Comment: isn't this missing a method to de-serialize the object from the json? ActiveJob should document this, but I can't find it at the moment...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `card.to_json` instead. It will return a JSON string that the job will be able to accept.

If you have logic you want to use with `as_json` just chain `to_json` to the end of the call to `as_json` i.e. `card.as_json.to_json`.